# HTML validation error in the SO Flair

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair

**There seems to be an HTML validation error in the SO Flair. Will it be fixed?**

I have included my SO flair in my site. I am a "Valid HTML" freak and will sometimes care so much about passing the W3 Validator that I'd forget the practical world :D

When I validate my site I get this -

> cannot generate system identifier for
>   general entity "A"
>
> …file for Senthil at Stack Overflow,
>   Q&A for professional and enthusiast
>   progra…

In the `Q&A` part, the `&` should be `& amp ;` (remove the spaces)

I know it is not a big deal, but for some people who just cannot sleep without passing the validator, It will be nice if it is changed :P Has anyone ever noticed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch -- my mistake, have been meaning to fix that.

Comment: When is this going to be fixed?

Comment: @olli this was fixed, but regressed when we switched from .aspx to razor. I'll begin beating the responsible individuals..