# Accepted answers without accept-votes show misleading "loading" tooltip

Tags: bug, answers, accepted-answer, deleted-accounts, tooltips

At present, accept-votes are transferred to Community when the question owner gets deleted. But this was not the case in the past, which is why Stack Overflow has over 15000 [accepted answers without accept-vote](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220047/accepted-answers-without-accept-vote).  Answers also enter this category when votes are invalidated because of serial voting.

When hovering over the checkmark on such answers, one sees the tooltip: "loading when this answer was accepted...", for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71043/) (screenshot below). This is misleading: no matter how long one waits, or how many times one moves the pointer to and from the checkmark, this information will not be loaded.

I suggest displaying "The question owner accepted this as the best answer", without a date. (In fact, this could replace the "loading" tooltip  on  all  occasions when the accept time fails to load.)

Another solution would be to restore those accept-votes if the required information is still present somewhere.

---

#### Not a duplicate of

- [The "loading when this answer was accepted" tooltip won't go away by itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166144/)
- ["Loading when the answer was accepted" tooltip prevails when closing as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215517/)

as those questions concern different scenarios when the "loading" tooltip is shown.

---

#### Screenshot

[image: loading...]